# How to figure out configuration difference of two separate Ubuntu/Linux installed systems?

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, aws

I have a custom made an old `AMI` (Amazon Machine Image) which is based on `ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server` public AMI. I plan to replace this custom image with the latest public image of `ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server`.

I plan to setup plain systems based on those images, compare and list the main configuration difference and inspect one by one for the necessary changes.

Is there any recommended way to quickly figure out the difference of two separate Ubuntu/Linux systems, such as to compare certain configuration directories and the files?

Comment: I would myself always add files I changes to a backup along with the personal data. When you need to restore a system you want all those changes also to be restored. If you did the same all you need is a filelist of your backup.

Answer (score 1):

if those all are based on ubuntu you can diff the `/etc` folder and its contents for configs. However, this may not be all. Some software can be downloaded to custom folders (like `/usr/share` or others) and this may require some further investigation.

You can also start from checking installed software by using:
`apt list --installed` (ths will also give you specific versions)

for comparing folders you can use `meld` package, with it's 3-way compare, but you will need to have WindowManager running for this. Other than that, simple diff tool is advised.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way to compare folders on separate systems need to mount the directories of at least on of those systems.

Comment: not really true, and there are threads about this: https://serverfault.com/questions/59140/how-do-diff-over-ssh
but I'd still prefer the network mount like you did and remove it after, so good work!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done:

- Initialized 2 separate instances, one with custom made Ubuntu AMI and another one with public Ubuntu 14.04 AMI
- Mounted the root directories of both instances to the local system and compared the difference of overall files and directories, however the diff was too large.
- Reduced the scope of comparison into certain directories as `/etc`, `/home`, `/opt` and also focused:

  - Users and groups (`/etc/group`)
  - Mount information (`/etc/fstab`)
  - Scheduled jobs (`/etc/cron*`)
- Compared the list of installed packages. Found large number of package differences because when listing all installed packages it includes main packages and their dependencies.
- Developed a script to build dependency structure of the installed packages to get the difference of main installed packages.

Above steps missing a lot for an exact comparison but helped me to proceed forward to get the difference of both systems. For further investigation [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024114/location-of-ini-config-files-in-linux-unix), [this](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-directory-structure-and-important-files-paths-explained) and [this](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/Guide_to_linux_configuration_files) might give a better idea.